# Parsing a String using Java regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the below java string in the below format.

```
externalCustomerID: { \"custToken\": \"xyz\" }
```

I want to extract xyz value from above string.
can anyone suggest me any regex expression for that in java?

Comment: is this the string "custToken": "xyz"  or it's externalCustomerID: { "custToken": "xyz" }

Comment: externalCustomerID: { "custToken": "xyz" } this is my input string

Comment: you can use `JSONParser` to read the value. Go through below link to understand more about the JSONParser.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 1):

check this one

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+: \\{ \"\\w+\": \")(\\w+)");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("externalCustomerID: { \"custToken\": \"xyz\" }");

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Comment: you welcome :) you can use this site to test and verify your regex https://regex101.com/ make sure to choose java flavor from the left side

Comment: sorry @user16320675 it did not get what you mean